# Is it possible to deploy program with Solana SDK

Tags: solana, anchor-solana, solana-cli

There are many examples and tutorials on how to deploy Solana account using anchor framework or the native way.

I can successfully deploy account and update its field with anchor SDK & IDL. However, I have to manually using the Solana CLI to deploy the program and its code beforehand.

I'm just wondering is it also possible to deploy program using Solana SDK since each program is also a type of account which is executable, and its owner program is the BPF upgradeable uploader.

Comment: It is technically possible, which is why the program loader bindings are available in the JS package: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/library-legacy/src/bpf-loader.ts -- this method isn't recommended however

Comment: Hi @JonC, thanks for the comment, but why it is not recommended?
I'm just thinking it as interacting with another program, so perhaps I can also load the BPF loader's IDL and send out the deploy instruction?

Comment: Typically to deploy a program, you want to send a lot of transactions quickly, which the JS library isn't suited for. Most programs require around ~1k transactions to upload to the network. It's more of a footgun than anything else to try to deploy a program using JS. With the Rust SDK, however, feel free!

Comment: Ah got it, and it also wouldn't recommended using other language like for example Golang?

Comment: Also, I saw that solana playground has implemented program deployment using JS as well: https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground/blob/cd77e52d53e67f00daad977bea305f03cf4df4d2/vscode/src/commands/deploy/deploy.ts#L19

Comment: You can certainly use all of these things! The main advantage of the Rust SDK is using the TPU client to spray transactions at the network, rather than being forced to go through RPC on the JS or Golang side, assuming that there's no TPU client for either language.